# How to use HighCharts dart library in Flutter app?

Tags: highcharts, dart, flutter

I'm looking into using HighCharts Dart library to build visualisation for my flutter app. Base on the example [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/highcharts), I'm not too sure how to integrate it into the flutter app.

After looking around, it seems like there isn't chart library for flutter app, other than building from scratch. Do you know if this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9043) has been addressed or still in progress?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The one you linked to won't work in Flutter, it just wraps a JS package. Flutter doesn't run JS. In flutter you need a Flutter native one.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you know any chart libraries I can use for buildinng Flutter app?

Comment: I don't think there is one yet. If there is one, I'm sure you can find it in pub.dartlang.org. If it has the Web icon, it probably won't work on Flutter.

Comment: ok thanks for the helps anyway.

Comment: What kind of chart view do you need? Actually, I'm building a radar chart in flutter, but it takes some more time to complete.

Comment: I'm also looking for a Highchats integration with Flutter. Do you guys know of any library that does that ?

Answer (score 1):

I know your looking for direct integration, but you can use the node export server.

https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/256-introducing-the-highcharts-node-js-export-server/

How I use it is, I post to highchairs on the server, get the SVG, and display that in flutter.  It's not as nice as local, but it works for a good number of use cases.

The same technique can be applied using any server-side SVG chart renderer.

Comment: You are aware that Flutter doesn't run on JS (like React or Xamarin)

Comment: You are aware my answer is server side technology, as stated in the last sentence of my answer.  You post your data, the server creates and replies with the svg, then the client (flutter) renders it

Comment: I see. Worth a try but SVG support is also still quite limited.

Comment: You could always use png, but SVG has the ability for basic interactivity.  We do this, exact technique using pygal (http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/output.html) it works fine for our use cases.